# Location of Georeferencer in QGIS Las Palmas

Tags: georeferencing

I can't find the georeferencer in qGIS las Palmas 2.18

Answer (score 0):

Did you search for it in plugins? You have to turn the plugin on in order to Georeferencer to appear in Raster 'section'.